# React Native without Android Studio?

Tags: android, react-native, ubuntu-18.04

Is there any way to develop a React Native app for Android without installing Android Studio ?

On Ubuntu 18.04 the apt command proposes a lot of android packages: android-sdk, android-sdk-platform-tools etc...

What do I need exactly to get React Native working properly ?

Answer (score 4):

Please don't use expo or another SDKs of react native. React Native CLI is recommended everywhere because its performance is not comparable to expo and it is much more lightweight! Android Studio is just an IDE! If you setup your android development environment correctly there is no need to install Android Studio IDE (This is for experts!) but it is recommended to install for amateur users.

Comment: Thanks, I think I'm gonna take your advice. But can you tell me please where can I download the Android SDK in stand alone mode (ie: without Android Studio and the rest of it) ?

Comment: Google it. But the easiest way to run up is Android Studio

Answer (score 3):

you don't need Android Studio at all, if you are using react native cli you can install it on your phone and run it there.

Answer (score 2):

If you don't want to use the `Android studio`, you can take advantage of the `Expo`. `Expo` is the best way to assist `React-native`. You can run the app without the `Android studio`, and when you refresh, you can see the modified code right away.

Look at [this official document](https://docs.expo.io/versions/latest/) and follow it slowly.

Comment: I already use Expo, but now I want to use the mobile phone camera so I need the React Native CLI.

Comment: Why can't I use an Expo to use a mobile phone camera?

Comment: I'm new to React Native/Expo but according to some tutorials I read, all the device  components as camera and so forth are accessible only through Java (Android) or Objective C (iOS)

Comment: There is a camera module already implemented by that code in expo.

Comment: Indeed, as well as other device components as Audio, Accelerometer etc...
Does it mean that with Expo I can access all the mobile phone components ?

Comment: Yes, Expo's camera modules are made by referring to the React-Native-Camera Module.

Answer (score 0):

An attempt of solution to use react native without android studio and without expo is to build directly in your device.

- you must install adb first by following this link [install-adb-fastboot-on-ubuntu 18.04](https://computingforgeeks.com/install-adb-fastboot-on-ubuntu-mint/)
- and then you should follow this link [react-native running-on-device](https://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/running-on-device)
  It will help you.

I'm using usb cable to install debug apk in my phone (react-native run-android). I put my phone in the same network (WIFI) with my machine (server) and configure the server address and port to debug remotely in the phone. After that i remove the usb cable.

In short everything is explained on the link above

Comment: Thanks for the tip, I didn't know this method.
Can I access anything on my mobile phone as I would with Android Studio ?

Comment: what i know is that : 
- you can access all options menu by shaking your phone
- Through this, you can activate **debug JS remotely** and use your browser (like chrome) or the tool **React Native Debugger** (https://github.com/jhen0409/react-native-debugger/blob/master/docs/getting-started.md) 
- Through this again you can activate **hot reloading**, **live reloading**, in fact all the possible options of this menu.
- you can use your mobile phone camera